# Pattern matching based on parts of Head

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I want to find a function (could be user-defined) from an expression based on pattern matching.
However, I do not know the exact name (Head) of the function but know only the first few characters.

Say

```
expr= 2 x + x^2 FunC[1,x] + x^3 FunC[2,x];
```

Now if I knew the full name of the function (in this case `FunC`), then I could do something like

```
Cases[expr,_FunC,All]
```

> {FunC[1, x], FunC[2, x]}

to access the occurrence of `FunC`.

However, say *I do not know* the full name/Head of the pattern,
I know that it starts with `Fun` (or ends with `unC`).
In that case,
**how do I access the occurrence of `FunC` in the expression using part of the Head?**

Something like

```
 Cases[expr,_pattern_,All]
```

where `_pattern_` could be part of the actual name/Head like `Fun`, `unC`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Cases[expr, _?(StringMatchQ[ToString[Head[#]], "Fun*"] &), All]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = 2 x + x^2 MyFun1[1, x] + x^3 MyFun2[2, x];

p = Position[expr, x_ /; StringMatchQ[ToString[x], "My*"], {}, Heads -> False]
```

{{2, 2}, {3, 2}}

```
Extract[expr, p]
```

{MyFun1[1, x], MyFun2[2, x]}

```
q = Position[expr, x_ /; StringMatchQ[ToString[x], "My*"], {-1}]
```

{{2, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 0}}

```
Extract[expr, q]
```

{MyFun1, MyFun2}